# How to add SharePoint Framework Extensions to gear menu dynamically?

Tags: spfx

Modern SharePoint supports Framework Extensions and I was wondering what is the easiest and the most future proof way to add new options to Gear menu (⚙️) dynamically with these Extensions?

I know there are top and bottom placeholders, but is there a placeholder for adding items to Gear menu?

What I would like to have is an Application Customizer that shows certain actions in Gear menu for certain people. e.g. **List Metadata** option that Lists all metadata of the current site
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top and bottom placeholders are the only placeholders available as of now.

Secondly, the rendering of items in the Gear menu is controlled by Microsoft. So, in SharePoint online, its not recommended to customise it because changes pushed by Microsoft might overwrite your customisation.

So, what i would recommend is that you insert a button in the top placeholder and then on the click of it, show the metadata of the site by making an AJAX request. The permission checking for a group of people can be done via REST calls. That way, you will be able to control the visibility of the button.